# Creation large of bitstring

Tags: c++, bitset

I need to create large bitstring and get pointer to memory where it is stored (requirement of API I'm using). Is there a library to do it in C++?

I've looked on boost::dynamic_bitset, std::vector and std::bitset but they unfortunately hide the internal details (and are not resizable in case of std::bitset). I'm creating currently the string using boost::dynamic_bitset and copying it but I would prefer to do it in place for convenience/performance.

**EDIT**: The API mentioned before is passing the memory via the PCI-E to the external device. The bitstring can be thought as a specialised instruction to some extend which are created on the fly by the CPU. The API is rather low-level (it gets a pointer to memory and size of it and sends it to device).

Comment: What datatype exactly does the API you write about require? You can use a suitable type internally, while creating a wrapper class to the outside that gives e.g. the bitwise access. For better advise, you'll have to provide more details though.

Comment: The API is on pointer level and is basically sending it to external device by PCI-E (+ handling a bit of bookkeeping & co.). I need however to generate the non-byte aligned data for it - I started wondering if there is ready to use class to handle such creation.

Comment: Care to share what it's supposed to point to? I'd suggest vector<uint8_t> for storing raw bytes and build anything on top of it.

Comment: It's suppose to point to memory containing bitsting - i.e. in byte 0 first 8 bits, in byte 1 next 8 bits etc.. `vector<uint8_t>` have the disadvantage of not having simple method of saying "append those 14 bits at the end" and I need to take care about it myself (which is possible but the question is about ready solutions) - arguably `dynamic_bitsting` + copying is easier solution in this case.

Comment: since std::vector has contiguous storage - you could just get the address of the first element ?

Comment: @IwanAucamp: I could but this was not the point of my comment. `std::vector` does not have primitive 'append 14 bits at the end' so I would need to do it by hand - see my previous comment. (Project is done so any discussion is for benefit of people looking for answer).